# Trigger deployment button in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I'm setting up a Continuous Delivery pipeline for my team with Jenkins. As a final step, we want to deploy to AWS.

I came across this while searching: [image: Jenkins Pipeline]:

The last step is a button where you can click to trigger deploying. Very nice! However, I searched throw Jenkins plugins page but I don't think it is there (or it is under a vague name).

Any ideas what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is a button to trigger an operation in the plugin. It was hard to detect as the UI of the plugin is redesigned and the button became smaller.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specific plugin you are looking for, but there is a Jenkins plugin for CodeDeploy, which can automatically create a deployment as a post-build action. See: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-codedeploy-plugin

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how what kind of requirements you have on the actual deployment procedure. One thing to keep in mind if you do infrastructure as code to setup your pipelines automatically (e.g. through JobDSL or Jenkins Job Builder), is that the particular plugins must be supported. For that reason it some times might be more convenient to just script your deployments instead of relying on plugins. I've implemented multiple deployment jobs from Jenkins to AWS by just using plain AWS CLI commands, e.g. triggering Cloudformation creation/updates.